# What are the conditions that should be satisfied to know that an estimator is biased?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, estimation, parameter-estimation

If I know that the variance of an estimator is less than the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound, does this mean for sure that it is a biased estimator?

Comment: Yes. $\qquad\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Bound_on_the_variance_of_biased_estimators) that this would indicate that the gradient of the bias function evaluated at the parameter would be negative, but I don't necessarily think that you couldn't have a biased estimator with higher variance. I think, according to that link, that the gradient can't be too negative either. There seems to be a sweet spot of the bias function where you can have lower variance with an estimator.